# Requiring extended permissions with the JS SDK without necessarily using FB.login()

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-authentication

I'm working on a canvas app and I want to accomplish the following with the JS SDK:

- Check if the user has granted specific extended permissions

  - If so, call some function startServerProcess()
  - If not, display the auth dialog to get permissions and alert the user if they don't provide sufficient access.

I want to completely handle this on the client-side such that startServerProcess() is never called unless the user provides the right permissions, given that the server script it executes relies on these permissions.

After searching I found [this solution](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/7397325/facebook-js-sdk-post-to-wall-after-permissions-check), but it solely uses FB.login() which I don't want to call every time, because if the user is already authenticated, an annoying auth dialog opens and then automatically closes immediately after.

My initial solution is to call FB.getLoginStatus() and then make a graph api call to /me/permissions if possible and only call FB.login() if I actually have to show an auth dialog.

Here's the code I have as of now:

```
$('#my_ui_button').click(function() {
    require_perms(function(is_authenticated) {
        if(!is_authenticated) {
            startServerProcess();
        } else {
            alert('Sorry, we cannot start the server process until you grant permission');
        }
    });
});


function require_perms(callback) {
    // check if the user is logged in + connected to the app
    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {

        // if the user is logged in, continue to check permissions
        if(response.authResponse) {
            FB.api('/me/permissions', function(perms_response) {

                // if photo access already exists, we're good to go
                if(perms_response['data'][0]['user_photos'] && perms_response['data'][0]['friends_photos']) {
                    console.log('permissions are already granted.');
                    callback(true);

                    // photo access does not exist, so show an auth dialog
                } else {

                    // get photo permissions
                    console.log('requesting permission...');
                    FB.login(function(response) {
                        if(response.authResponse) {
                            console.log('permission granted');
                            callback(true);
                        } else {
                            console.log('permission request failed');
                            callback(false);
                        }
                    }, {
                        scope : 'user_photos,friends_photos'
                    });
                }
            });
            // user is not connected to the app, so show an auth dialog
        } else {

            // get photo permissions
            console.log('requesting permission...');
            FB.login(function(response) {
                if(response.authResponse) {
                    console.log('permission granted');
                    callback(true);
                } else {
                    console.log('permission request failed');
                    callback(false);
                }
            }, {
                scope : 'user_photos,friends_photos'
            });
        }
    });
}
```

---

Does this seem like a messy way of solving the problem?  I particularly don't like the fact that I'm repeating that FB.login() code but I ran into some issues eliminating that given the asynchronous nature of the graph api call (or maybe I just need some more sleep).

Any comments/advice would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: You can simply take out a function called askForPermissions(callback) and remove your code duplication with it. beside this your solution is the right way to go. IMO

Answer (score 1):

I think this is significantly over-complicating what could just be achieved with FB.login(). FB.login() will only cause the pop up if the user is not logged in (so they will need it anyway) or if the session cookie isn't available. You could just call FB.getLoginStatus() after initialising the page which will make sure the cookie is added immediately if available.

The pop up is pretty much unavoidable, and is standard behaviour on most apps. I don't think your solution would gain much over simply:

```
FB.init({...});
FB.getLoginStatus();
```

then

```
FB.login({},{scope:...});
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.

FB.login() is causing a pop-up even if the user is logged in and the requested permissions have already been granted.  The auth dialog window starts to open/load and then immediately closes (when permissions are already granted).  If permissions haven't yet been granted, it doesn't automatically close and it shows the appropriate dialog.  Does this not happen when you do it?

It's specifically the open/close of the dialog when permissions are already granted that I'm trying to avoid with the code I posted above.

Comment: yes, the pop up will be showing because there is no session cookie yet. The user is logged in and has accepted permissions, but your website doesn't know that yet. It has to pop up to ask facebook what their status is, then realises they are sorted already, so it sets the cookie and closes immediately. Try watching for the fbsr_[app_id] cookie with an add on, as you try different scenarios. So long as you FB.init with cookie: true then you will see this behaviour. Once the cookie is there, the pop up wont show again. If the user never loses the cookie, they will only get the pop up once.

Comment: as you suggested, i took a look at the behavior of the fbsr_[app_id] cookie, and i actually don't think it has anything to do with the pop-up. i must have had something really messed up before because i can't reproduce the pop-up open/close issue i was seeing earlier. im seeing now that even if i manually delete the fbsr cookie from my browser, FB.login remembers that i'm connected and won't show the pop-up on subsequent calls.  calling FB.getLoginStatus will re-set the cookie, but the cookie itself doesn't seem to affect the outcome of FB.login.

Comment: if i go on a different browser and remove/de-authorize the app, calling FB.login again on the original browser session doesn't result in any difference - it still thinks i'm authorized and shows no pop-up (cookie or no cookie).  the state only updates after i refresh the page on the original browser session OR call FB.getLoginStatus(), after which FB.login will show the pop-up, as expected.  so i think that makes sense to me - now im just puzzled as to what was causing the open/instant-close of the auth pop-up that i was seeing before...

Comment: actually, i just figured this out.  in my most recent comment(s) i was testing this with FB.login using no extra permissions (e.g. no scope parameter).  it worked pretty much as expected when i did that (as i described above).  however, if the only thing i change is adding in the scope parameter to require extended permissions, i get the pop-up open/instant-close issue.  i still maintain that i believe this does NOT have anything to do with cookies and i haven't found a better solution than the code i posted in my original question.  any further ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Use oAuth Dialog.According to documentation it Prompts the user to grant permissions to your application.
Direct the user's browser to
http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth/?
  scope=email,user_birthday&
  client_id=123050457758183&
  redirect_uri=http://www.example.com/response&
  response_type=token

check this link for full documntation : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/oauth/

Comment: While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

I do not see a problem in your approach. One cause that should be also considered though is the browser cashing or server update issues. Make sure that you are testing the latest version of your code. Testing the app in a new browser will be often a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

Last two days I have exact the same problem but finally I solved it. In the development phase I had only tested the application with my own facebook account and I didn't see any error with Facebook login screen, but when I started to test the application with other facebook accounts (which has not a tester or developer user for my application), I encountered this problem. It is fixed after I add these users as Tester (from Application->Settings->Develeoper Roles) to my application. I hope this works.